# Quick documentation (alt + click) not working

Tags: xcode, documentation

When I try to open the quick documentation popup, it doesn't work. My cursor changes to question mark on alt click, but clicking on anything doesn't open the documentation popup.

I am running the latest XCode version.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Is there any possible fix? Restarting XCode did not help.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this an issue for all code, or just methods/classes that you document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it was caused by 3rd party app called "Flexiglass".